# combine results on many sql queries without using cartesian join

Tags: mysql

How can I combine results of following multiple select queries so that I can have information about all battles in one combined view. for complete schema please look [here](https://pastebin.com/UfmzT5t0) as stackoverflow limits how much code I can write to describe my problem.

```
|battle.id  |Attackers       | Defender           | Winner         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1      |'rishabhchauhan'|'vaibhavchauhan'    |'vaibhavchauhan'|
|    2      |'abhishekgaur'  |'vaibhavchauhan'    |'vaibhavchauhan'|
|    3      |'AnkitSharma'   |'vaibhavchauhan'    |'vaibhavchauhan'|
....
```

Query to find attacker name:

```
select CONCAT(player.firstname, player.lastname) as Attacker, Battles.battle_id 
from ((player inner 
join Attacker_Battles on Attacker_Battles.player_id = player.player_id ) 
inner join Battles on Battles.battle_id = Attacker_Battles.battle_id);
```

Query to find defender name:

```
select CONCAT(player.firstname, player.lastname) as Defenders, Battles.battle_id 
from ((player inner 
join Defender_Battles on Defender_Battles.player_id = player.player_id ) 
inner join Battles on Battles.battle_id = Defender_Battles.battle_id);
```

Query to find winner name:

```
select CONCAT(player.firstname, player.lastname) as Winners, Battles.battle_id 
from ((player inner 
join Winner_battles on Winner_battles.player_id = player.player_id ) 
inner join Battles on Battles.battle_id = Winner_battles.battle_id);
```

Comment: Generally, you only need a dozen or so rows to communicate a given problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine all the queries into one, you just need to `JOIN` the `Battles` table to each of the `Attacker_Battles` etc. tables, and then each of those to the `player` table to get the appropriate name. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pa.firstname, pa.lastname) AS Attacker,
       CONCAT(pd.firstname, pd.lastname) AS Defender,
       CONCAT(pw.firstname, pw.lastname) AS Winner,
       b.battle_id As Battle
FROM Battles b
JOIN Attacker_Battles ab ON ab.battle_id = b.battle_id
JOIN player pa ON pa.player_id = ab.player_id
JOIN Defender_Battles db ON db.battle_id = b.battle_id
JOIN player pd ON pd.player_id = db.player_id
JOIN Winner_Battles wb ON wb.battle_id = b.battle_id
JOIN player pw ON pw.player_id = wb.player_id
```

Output (for your pastebin data)

```
Attacker        Defender        Winner          Battle
rishabhchauhan  vaibhavchauhan  vaibhavchauhan  1
abhishekgaur    pawanyadav      abhishekgaur    2
abhishekgaur    pawanyadav      abhishekgaur    3
AnkitSharma     JayantVerma     AnkitSharma     4
vaibhavchauhan  JayantVerma     JayantVerma     5
rishabhchauhan  abhishekgaur    rishabhchauhan  6
vaibhavchauhan  AnkitSharma     vaibhavchauhan  8
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b82421/1)

The query can also be written (perhaps a little more intuitively) as below. If it is possible that a given `Battle` might not have an `Attacker`, `Defender` and `Winner`, the top level `JOIN`s in this query can be replaced with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pa.firstname, pa.lastname) AS Attacker,
       CONCAT(pd.firstname, pd.lastname) AS Defender,
       CONCAT(pw.firstname, pw.lastname) AS Winner,
       b.battle_id As Battle
FROM Battles b
JOIN (Attacker_Battles ab
      JOIN player pa ON pa.player_id = ab.player_id) ON ab.battle_id = b.battle_id
JOIN (Defender_Battles db
      JOIN player pd ON pd.player_id = db.player_id) ON db.battle_id = b.battle_id
JOIN (Winner_Battles wb
      JOIN player pw ON pw.player_id = wb.player_id) ON wb.battle_id = b.battle_id
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b82421/3)

Comment: hey, @nick this works, however I am trying to understand that why does it work , from what I can infer by looking at the code is that you were able to do left join among for result for finding Attacker_Battles result set, resulting result set was further joined on Defender_Battles result set and finally resulting result set was joined upon, Winner_Battles. 

on the side note, if it were you how would you breakup this database schema?

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan The query assumes that each battle has a corresponding entry in `Attacker_Battles`, `Defender_Battles` and `Winning_Battles`. Once we have those three entries we can `JOIN` to `players` 3 times to get the 3 different names (one each for `Attacker`, `Defender` and `Winning`.

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan If I was gong to change the schema, I would probably put the various player ids directly into `Battles` as well as a flag to indicate which player (attacker or defender) won the battle. Then you don't need the `Attacker_Battles`, `Defender_Battles` and `Winning_Battles` tables.

Comment: I was going to do that too in the beginning, I stopped short of doing that thinking maybe we should leave a possibility of having multiple attackers/defenders/winners, i.e. attacking_team, defending_team, winning_team, even though it was not part of the requirements, but we sure know how quickly they change in real life :D

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan You are so right! If a team is a possibility, you will definitely need a different structure. You might want to include `attacking_team`, `defending_team` and `winner` in `Battles`, and then have a `Teams` table which had `team_id`, `team_name` and `player_id`s

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan I've added an alternate form of writing the query which I think it a bit more intuitive in terms of understanding and also allows for the possibility of a battle not having attackers, defenders and a winner.